# If has tag, get tag, else. [Wordpress, PHP, Function]

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get wordpress to show tag if there is a tag. but when there is no tag, other element are affected and hidden if there is no tag. I want it to show "No tag Available", when there is no tag, not hiding the whole element.

```html
if ( !has_tag() ) return;
    $tags = get_the_tags(); 
    foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
        $tag_link = get_tag_link( $tag->term_id );    
    }
 
    echo "<li class='list-group-item'><a href='{$url}' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'><strong>Original Size</strong> ({$original_w}x{$original_h})</a>&nbsp;<a href='{$tag_link}' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'><strong>Show more {$tag->name} wallpaper</strong></a></li>";
```

When there is a tag in the post
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tl06G.png

When there is no tag in the post
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUyAZ.png

I want to show the elements even where there is no tag in the post.

FYI, I newbie to PHP.

Comment: so if there is no tag how you show tags?

Comment: What have you tried to debug that problem? Using `return` when `has_tag()` returns false might be a good starting point

Answer (score 0):

Your code is just a bit scrambled here. You need to check if `$tags` is empty or not. `$tags` will be empty if there is no tags, which means `get_the_tags` returns an empty array.

You can do something like this

```
$tags = get_the_tags();

if($tags) {
    //your foreach loop to show tags
}else{
    // show something else if there are no tags
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. this worked for me.

```html
   <div class="post-tags">
  <?php
global $post;
if(has_tag()){
foreach(get_the_tags($post->ID) as $tag)
{
        echo '<a href="' . get_tag_link($tag->term_id) . '">' . $tag->name . '</a>';

}
}else{
echo 'No tags available';
}

?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have already received good answers, I'd like to add something general:

You can also use the PHP function [`count()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) to count the number of items in an array. This will give you a somewhat more precise information and not only "has tags" or "has no tags".

If you save the result of `count()` in a variable, you can use it in conditional statements like [`switch`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) or if-clauses, like already shown.